# How to support multi-GPU systems in Media Foundation?

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, ms-media-foundation

I need to create D3D device and context on the correct GPU, which is the GPU implementing the encoder.

The documentation for `MFT_ENUM_ADAPTER_LUID` says it requires Windows 10, in reality the NVENC MFT doesn’t expose that attribute even on Win10.

The documentation for `MFT_ENUM_HARDWARE_URL_Attribute` says the value  is the symbolic link for the device driver, in reality the NVENC MFT doesn’t return any GUID links, the value is the same as in `MFT_FRIENDLY_NAME_Attribute`, specifically `L"NVIDIA H.264 Encoder MFT"`

`MFT_ENUM_HARDWARE_VENDOR_ID_Attribute` appears to work OK, returns `L"VEN_10DE"`so I can parse that into a number and match against `VendorId` field of `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC` structure. However the documentation for that attribute says the support is optional.

I don’t like optional, I want reliable. How to match hardware encoder MFTs to GPUs? There’re upcoming PCs with two GPUs both by AMD, like Asus FX505DY, the vendor ID trick won’t work on such systems.

Answer (score 1):

MFT instances [at instantiation stage at least] are not device specific. If you have two NVENC-enabled video adapters in your system, the encoder MFT is the same, with the same CLSID.

You specify the GPU to use by means of [`MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/mft-message-set-d3d-manager) message, which parameter wraps a D3D device and is GPU specific. This is where you select GPU for the encoder.

Also FYI NVIDIA H.264 Encoder MFT specifically fails to work correctly with anything but primary video adapter (including but not limited to [this](http://alax.info/blog/1830)), if not everywhere the at least in great number of systems out there. In my understanding it's Nvidia's bug they are to fix in their MFT implementation.

Comment: Aren’t encoders device specific when GPUs are different? When client tested my code on a system with 2 GPUs, with nVidia’s encoder and Intel’s D3D device MF fell back to software encoding. I don’t know what will happen on Asus FX505DY because I don’t have that hardware but I’d expect it to have 2 instances of AMD’s encoder, one per GPU.

Yes I’m using the D3D manager, albeit in different way, with MF_SINK_WRITER_D3D_MANAGER. But it happens later, before creating the manager I need the device context.

Comment: In a system with 2 AMD GPUs you start with the same CLSID anyway: both adapters have the same MFT class implementing hardware encoder. `CoCreateInstance` creates identical encoder instances which then are initialized with GPU reference in the form of D3D manager backed in turn by D3D device, which is in its turn GPU specific.